# Fire multiple selectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf

When this event is fired:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

I need to fire also

```
 private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

inside the DataGrid_SelectionChanged, how can I convert the sender? Thanks.

Comment: Those are methods, not `event`s. And `event`s can only be raised by the enclosing type that defined them. If you wanna call the other method when the first method is called you should do it manually.

Comment: just pass your tab control abject when calling this event handler method..
`TabControl_SelectionChanged(tabControl1, null);` or you can bind both controls event to the same event handler.
`DataGrid_SelectionChanged += Control_SelectionChange;
TabControl.SelectionChanged += Control_SelectionChange;`

Comment: **This is bad practice.** You can call the second handler from the first, but you end up with confusing code, and soon enough you'll be adding weird special cases to avoid *some* of the code in the second handler. If you have some code that needs to happen when the TabControl selection changes *and* when the DataGrid selection changes, put that code in another method in the same class, and give that method an appropriate name that describes what it does. Call it from both handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Whats preventing you to call like so?

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    . . .
    TabControl_SelectionChanged(yourTabControl, e);
    . . .
}
```

Comment: is this a good practice?

Comment: @MarioSerda No, it isn't. What is the actual goal here? Why do you say you need to simulate the TabControl's SelectionChanged event?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it.